# innobackupex - get output from command line

Tags: php, mysql, linux, percona

I'm running the `innobackupex` script, but I don't know how to fetch the output from the script? I need the last line to check if the script succeeded or failed..

```
$output = shell_exec('innobackupex --user=root --password=xxx --databases="test" --stream=tar ./ | gzip -c -1 > /var/bak/2013-08-09-1431_mysql.tar.gz')
```

The script is working as it should and the backup zip is created, but `$output` is empty

## update

now the command is not being piped through to gzip, but still no output

```
$syntax = 'innobackupex --user='.$mysql_user.' --password='.$mysql_pass.' --databases="'.$mysql_db.'" /var/bak';
$output = shell_exec($syntax);
```

Comment: There is no output. You're writing it all to a file.

Comment: ok.. where can this file be found?

Comment: `/var/bak/2013-08-09-1431_mysql.tar.gz`

Comment: how can I then check if the last line ends with `completed OK!`?

Comment: Well you can't, all of the output from your `innobackupex` command is being piped through to `gzip`, which will then do its job and create the file that you requested.

Comment: It doesn't give sense if you can't check if the script has succeeded

Comment: So use it properly - let `innobackupex` create the backup files itself. `innobackupex --user=DBUSER --password=DBUSERPASS /path/to/BACKUP-DIR/`. You can them compress them in the background if you need to, or just run the compression separately.

Comment: have updated my question.. but still no output

Comment: Could you please try redirecting stderr to stdout by sticking this on the end? `2>&1` - Also does the backup still work (go into `/var/bak`) when you're running it like you are now?

Comment: ok, this works.. `innobackupex --user='.$mysql_user.' --password='.$mysql_pass.' --databases="'.$mysql_db.'" /var/bak 2>&1`.. but isn't it somehow possible to both get the output from the script and pipe the command through to gzip!?

Comment: No, because the output from the script is going to gzip. The only output you would get, would be from gzip itself.

Comment: ok.. please create an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't mean to step on @RudyVisser's answers in comments, but here's another solution:

```
$syntax = 'innobackupex --user="'.$mysql_user.'" --password="'.$mysql_pass.'"
  --databases="'.$mysql_db.'" --stream=tar ./ | gzip -c -1 
  > /var/bak/2013-08-09-1431_mysql.tar.gz ; echo $?')

$exit_status = shell_exec($syntax);
```

The echo inside the command should report the exit status of innobackupex, which is 0 if the backup was successful, and non-zero if there was an error.

http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/xtrabackup_bin/xtrabackup_exit_codes.html

PS:  Percona XtraBackup also has a `--compress` option that uses the **qpress** algorithm, known to be very fast.  I mention this because I notice you're using `gzip -1` presumably for better performance.